# Microsoft Graph API, 400 Bad Request

Tags: azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks

Microsoft Graph API return error 400 for each request.
Also when I try to make a request from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer its the same issue which this header:

ApiExProxy-Error: 1
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0

Any Idea about that?

Comment: It sounds like you are making this request from behind a corporate proxy that perhaps requires authentication.  Are you doing this from a work machine, or at home?

Comment: The problem was I used Microsoft sample code and the graph sdk "implementation 'com.microsoft.graph:msgraph-sdk-android:1.5.0' "
When I used the sdk as source code it was not working, I am not sure what was the problem but it seems the SDK source code version is 1.7.0 and maybe it doesn't compatible to the sample code. So I implemented the code from this link https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android#21-register-your-application and it works now,

Comment: Thanks for letting us know the problem and how you resolved it.  We will update our content so that others will not run into this issue.